# Is there an adjective that describes a movement as being non-fluid, robot-like?

Tags: word-request

Is there an adjective that describes a movement as being non-fluid, robot-like? Looked at the antonyms of "fluid", but I couldn't find the word I was looking for. Certainly, there must be an adjective that fit the above criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of:

- Stilted
- Jerky
- Mechanical
- Awkward
- Clumsy
- Robotic
- un-graceful

might do, depending on teh exact context.